# Account Linking Information won't update

Tags: actions-on-google

Anyone encountered an issue where you update the account linking information and the UI does indeed update, but the actual call to the server for authentication stays the same like it was before?

I have update the Client ID for my OAuth 2.0 server and the action still try to authenticate with the old Client ID.

I tried clearing, saving everything again, sending to draft and nothing happens.

The action is still in draft

Comment: Have you tried to create a new action with the new Client ID?

Comment: @IdoGreen New Action = New Project? if so then no, not yet.
The question is why wouldn't it update? 
Looks like a bug

Comment: did you tried to click in the action simulator on the right above the response and so tab on update draft choose there the only or newest option and press update and than try again

Comment: Yes, didn't help..

Comment: A couple things I'd try:
Either, 
1) After changing the auth settings, stop testing (in the simulator, top right), and restart it. See if the changes are reflected then.
OR 2) After changing the auth settings, run 'gactions update' with your existing action package, and then follow the steps above to restart tests.

Premise for my suggestion: Auth settings (console settings in general) correspond to Action Package. So reflecting action package (AP) changes requires restarting testing (you can only test on AP at a time)